# How to call Controller Method in a Controller in a different namespace in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I want to call a function of `CommonController` in `PostsController`.

PostsController is in Posting namespace

```
PostController: App\Http\Controllers\Posting\PostsController
CommonController: App\Http\Controllers\CommonController
```

I tried this code but it did not work in PostingController, it is a small code from my PostingController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Employer;
use App\Http\Controllers\CommonController;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
    public function myFunction(Request $request, $id){
        $commonControllerObj = new CommonContoller;
        $result = $commonControllerObj->commonCallingFunction($id);
    }
}
```

but it did not work, its giving error

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Posting\CommonContoller' not found
```

Comment: Can you update your controllers directory and `CommonController` file content into your question?

Answer (score 3):

The first your namespace is wrong

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Posting;
```

The second you can call another Controller like this

`app('App\Http\Controllers\CommonController')->commonCallingFunction();`

This will work, but this is bad in terms of code organisation

You can extends Controller like this

```
use App\Http\Controllers\CommonContoller;

class PostsController extends CommonContoller
{
    public function myFunction(Request $request, $id){
        $result = $this->commonCallingFunction($id);
    }
}
```